# I have a windows 7 desktop and need a way to restore deleted system backup purposely deleted by my ex wife

Tags: windows-7

On my PC windows 7 desktop. Going through a horrible divorce and my ex has been wiping everything.
Is there any way to restore deleted system backup files or any other way to undo her efforts and restore deleted data somehow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried running a tool like Recuva?

Comment: I have not tried that one but I have tried easels.